# Error when SSH forwarding TCP to unix socket

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, socket

I am trying to use `ssh` to forward a TCP connection on a local port to a Unix socket on a remote server, but I keep getting errors.

I started by having `nc` listen on the remote server:

```
remote$ nc -lU /tmp/socket
```

Then I set up a portforward using SSH:

```
local$ ssh -L127.0.0.1:5000:/tmp/socket -vv #remote host here#
```

The SSH and portforwarding seem to work:

```
debug1: Local connections to 127.0.0.1:5000 forwarded to remote address /tmp/socket:-2
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 5000.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 1: new [client-session]
```

Then I try to access `127.0.0.1:5000` in a browser, and I get this error message in my terminal:

```
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-streamlocal@openssh.com]
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-streamlocal@openssh.com: listening port 5000 for /tmp/socket port -2, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 41372 to 127.0.0.1 port 5000, nchannels 3
```

it comes up a bunch of times, and the connections fail.

How can I set this up? (I would prefer a solution which doesn't need root on the remote server or installing new software locally.)

Answer (score 1):

```
nc -klU /tmp/socket
```

Otherwise, nc will accept and handle one single connection and then exit. `-k` has nc fork off a new process to handle the incoming connection, and continue in it's accept() loop.

ssh seems overload "administartively prohibited" to also include, socket does not exist and socket-exists-but-nothing-is-listening.